# React, using useEffect to updata data, a data is a Array, but when I use map or Object.keys(data).map, both are not work. How to make it work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I used the useEffect to updata the data, I can see the data is a array in DEV tool, but when I using map to traverse the data, will show be that data.map is not a function. If I use Object.keys(data).map, there are not thing was showed, but no error...
How to fix ...?

```
export default function List() {
let [data, setData] = useState();
useEffect(async () => {
    let result = await loadList();
    console.log(result.data.data);
    setData({ data: result.data.data });
    return;
}, data);

return (
    <div>
        {
             (data) && data.map((item) => {
               return  <div key={item.id} >{item.title} author: {item.author}  Creact time: { item.creactetime}</div>
            })
        }
    </div>
)}
```

Comment: The dependency array for `useEffect` should be an array of variables. And you can't use an async callback in `useEffect`. Because those two are incorrect, `data` will never be updated and therefor can't be looped over.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier How can I do the ajax without async and  awaited here, If I don't use async, the data will delay?

Answer (score 2):

`useEffect` does not allow the use of an `async` function. Instead you should just use the `then` method when calling your `loadList` function and set the data in the callback.

It seems that `useEffect` doesn't need a dependency as it only needs to get the data on the first render, not when `data` changes. The latter would result in an infinite loop (Update `data` => do something when `data` updates => update `data`)

In `setData` just pass the `result.data.data` to update `data`, not within another object. Otherwise the data will not be an array, but an object.

```
export default function List() {
  let [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    loadList().then((result) => {
      setData(result.data.data);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {data &&
        data.map((item) => (
          <div key={item.id}>
            {item.title} author: {item.author} Creact time: {item.creactetime}
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

useEffect can not have an async callback you need to wrap it like this

```
useEffect(()=>{
const fetch = async () => {
    const result = await loadList();
   setData(result.data.data);
}
fetch();
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

`data` must be an array if you want to `map` on it, you can try to set directly `data` with `result.data.data` if it's an array, like following :

```
useEffect(async () => {
    let result = await loadList();
   setData(result.data.data);
}, []);
```